# Automatically logout a user when app is inactive for the fixed duration of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have requirement to automatically logout a user after some duration of time, and I am able to do that and logout app navigate to loginview but issue is that when I am on a view and performing some action like picking date from date picker or may I have other popup open at that time if app is logout then the popup or date picker or alert view  view displayed on login view.

So my question is how can I remove that from loginview . This is the code I am using to logout my application.

```
@implementation MyApplication

   - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       [super sendEvent:event];

    // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    if ([allTouches count] > 0) {

        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
              [self resetIdleTimer];
            NSLog(@"resetIdleTimer");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"no" forKey:@"istouch"];
    }

}

  -(void)resetIdleTimer {

    if (self.idleTimer) {
        [self.idleTimer invalidate];
    }
   NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[[User currentUser]AutomaticLogoutTime] doubleValue]*60;

    if (timeInterval > 0) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"istouch"];
          self.idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] ;

    }
}

-(void)idleTimerExceeded {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataUpdated"
                                                    object:self];
}
```

Comment: in viewWillDisapper, dismiss the alert/ popup

Comment: Yes! we can do that but we don't know it's pop/alert/date picker or others. The pop/alert/date picker is coming from other view. How would we get the instance of the subview of other view on my login view controller.

Comment: dismiss everything or have one variable that hold what is opened and dismiss accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

You can dismiss any viewcontroller which has been presented

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's a good habit to dismiss any kind of UIAlertController, ImagePicer... so on before your app is going to background your user will not be confused next time they bring the app to foreground.

lestin for notification and dismiss your presented controllers in right place